# Spring Boot - Spring.config.location

Tags: spring-boot

I have a strange scenario and i hope i could get some help.

I have a spring boot application on a server location. I use --spring.config.location property to specify application.properties in an external file path. 
My spring boot application additionally needs one more property file(lets say common.properties which required by application in addition to application.properties) which is present in same path as application.properties.

I am using a scheduling tool to invoke the spring boot jar and when i do it i use 
below command

{path of java}/java -jar {path of jar} --spring.config.location={path of application.properties and common.properties}/application.properties,{path of application.properties and common.properties}/common.properties

the paths where jars and property files are places are so long that my scheduling tool is not accepting to configure for triggering the job. I would like to know if there is a way i can get rid of using {path of application.properties and common.properties} redundantly to specify 2 times one each for application.properties and common.properties .

Note: i dont want to configure it any where in java code.

Comment: I suppose that you are using external config cause you have environment/staging/profile dependent configuration. Is the common.properties part of this env dependent configuration or is really common to all the instances? (ex. tes & prod with the same common.properties) ?

Comment: Yes, i am using external config for env dependent configuration. There are multiple jars which is dependent on a shared jar. Shared jar has many common.properties which is used based on environment. Did my response answer ur question??

Comment: so both application.properties and common. properties are environment dependent, but each one contains his hown environment dependent properites. am I right?

Comment: yes..you are right. after we deploy the sprint boot jar, both the property files application.properties and common.properties are on same path( lets say c:/test) . Responsibility of taking environment specific property files (application.properties and common.properties) and placing them in c:/test is taken care by deployment tool

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a directory to `--spring.config.location`

Unfortunately Spring will load only the file application.propertis and profile specific file like `application-{profile name}.properites`

if for you using a specific profile is not a problem( you don't use profile specific Benas exc.) you can rename your common.properties file into `application-common.properties` and than start your application with:

```
{path of java}/java -jar {path of jar} --spring.config.location=/path/of/both/properties --spring.profiles.active=common
```

remember that this way the application-common.properties will override any common properties in application.properties(as always with profile based properties)

Comment: i cant override application.properties. I need both property files for my application to process with out any issue

Comment: with spring you always override common properties if you have multiple properties files. Even with your current solution. if you don't have the same properties in both file you will not have problems